# mod_rewrite help when .htaccess is located in subdirectory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple rewrite rule that checks if a *.gz version of the requesting file exists, and if so returns that file to the browser (it's based around this technique for serving compressed CSS & JS: https://blog.jcoglan.com/2007/05/02/compress-javascript-and-css-without-touching-your-application-code/).

Assume that my CSS & JS reside in a /cache subdirectory of my site, e.g.:

```
http://domain.com/cache/app.css
http://domain.com/cache/app.css.gz
http://domain.com/cache/app.js
http://domain.com/cache/app.js.gz
```

When the following directives are placed within the .htaccess file at **webroot**, everything works as expected:

```
AddEncoding gzip .gz
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Safari
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.gz [QSA,L]
```

**However I'd prefer to place these rules within a separate .htaccess file that sits within that /cache directory.**  But pasted as-is, the rules no longer work.  From what I can tell, the last RewriteCond is failing, e.g. the condition which checks if the requested filename exists.

I've tried adding `RewriteBase /cache/` but that didn't seem to work. I've removed my webroot .htaccess in case there was another directive there that was conflicting. I've also tried changing the RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/$1.gz [QSA,L]
```

And while I think that might be correct in the end, it still doesn't work - like I said because from what I can tell it's the RewriteCond which is failing.

So I'm stumped! Any help?

Comment: Did you check the Apache logs? What files does it actually try to serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following rule should work from `/cache/.htaccess`:

```
AddEncoding gzip .gz
RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically/dynamically
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Safari
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:BASE}/$1\.gz -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.gz [L]
```

Comment: Where does the `$1` in `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1\.gz` come from?

Comment: `$1` comes from `RewriteRule` as `mod_rewrite` processes `RewriteRule` first.

Comment: Thank you very much, this does the trick! However it doesn't seem as though RewriteBase is necessary - and indeed when I remove that directive, everything still works. And could you explain the last RewriteRule, in particular the /? in the first part of the match?

Comment: Last RewriteRule actually captures everything except last taking slash by using `.+?` pattern, also note that last trailing slash is also made optional using `/?$`. And yes rewritebase line can be removed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - last question if you don't mind, is there any way to set this up so that 'cache' can be anything (and could be any depth)?